# matplotlib imread return an array of unit8, how to convert it to an array of float32?

Tags: arrays, matplotlib, types, imread

Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = plt.imread(<some image path>)
```

The `img` now is an array with `dtype = unit8`. How can I convert it into an array with `dtype = float32`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ndarray.astype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html):

```
img.astype('float32')
```